# Keyboard shortcuts with WPF and Powershell

Tags: wpf, powershell, keyboard-shortcuts

In the following code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
$window = New-Object Windows.Window
$commonKeyEvents = {
    [System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs] $e = $args[1]
    if ($e.Key -eq 'ESC') { $this.close() }
    if ($e.Key -eq 'Ctrl+Q') { $this.close() }
}
$window.add_PreViewKeyDown($commonKeyEvents)
$window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

the `'Ctrl+Q'` part does not work. How could I make this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you are:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
$window = New-Object Windows.Window

$commonKeyEvents = {
    [System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs] $e = $args[1]

    if (($e.Key -eq "Q" -and $e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers -eq "Ctrl") -or
        ($e.Key -eq "ESC")) {            
        $this.Close()
    }
}

$window.Add_PreViewKeyDown($commonKeyEvents)
$window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Simpler:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
$window = New-Object Windows.Window

$commonKeyEvents = {
    if (($_.Key -eq "Q" -and $_.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers -eq "Ctrl") -or
        ($_.Key -eq "ESC")) {            
        $this.Close()
    }
}

$window.Add_PreViewKeyDown($commonKeyEvents)
$window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I've been missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework
$window = New-Object Windows.Window
$commonKeyEvents = {
    [System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs]$e = $args[1]
    if ($e.Key -eq 'Escape') { $this.close() }
    if ([System.Windows.Input.KeyBoard]::Modifiers -eq [System.Windows.Input.ModifierKeys]::Control -and $e.Key -eq 'Q') { $this.close() }
}
$window.add_KeyDown($commonKeyEvents)
$window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```

Comment: Also not bad. Looks like a direct translation of some c# code I have seen which is not beautiful but works and serves me maybe to learn to translate the common WPF examples.